# Is anything without mass an EM wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, particle-physics, mass

For the longest time I thought the distinction between matter wave and other types of wave is the non-relativist mass of the "thing" under discussion. Photons are EM wave, electrons are matter waves.

The question is that is anything without mass an EM wave? Why or why not.

Comment: Note that there is more to a "thing" than its mass - there are all the charges under the other fundamental forces, which distinguish massless objects, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are massless particles which are not electromagnetic.

1. Gravitational waves - These are waves propagating through curved spacetime similar to EM waves in EM field. Gravitational waves have not been detected directly so far though strong indirect evidence exists for its existence.
2. Gluons (carriers of the strong force) are also massless.